# Optimal 2D tiling method

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm a bit confused with OpenGL ES 2.0 and I can't find any authoritive information on the correct procedure for handling 2D tiling (or maybe I have and I didn't understand it).

Quick and to the point, I currently have a few games based off Canvas (it's really not as bad as people say, I get FPS between 30-40 on a 1GHz CPU) and the performance is great, but I have some new ideas and I think OpenGL is the only way to get the performance I need to show my dazzling special effects.

I have a GameEngine with many thousands of hours in it, so I am a bit resistant to making huge architectural changes just to "test" things out if I can avoid it (especially since I'm new to OpenGL and can't afford the time to spend a month getting the peak performance (time = money).

I understand that Texture switching is VERY expensive. And already have a system in place for keeping texture regions on a single texture. I also keep track of which objects are on screen, so only the draw calls that are necessary to display the scene will be sent to the GPU.

So I have a ton of tiles/layers of tiles on the screen that have to be redrawn each frame. Would it be better to:

1. Parse my level files and turn each tile into a polygon (quad) linked to it's siblings etc, and create a UV map for it at load time? (This would require an architectural change from storing each tile as a Rectangle to keeping track of the points of neighboring tiles so they can be linked).
2. Create a single QUAD and move it around screen to all of the positions, taking care to render tiles that CAN be rendered on the same pass with the SAME texture.
3. Create a QUAD for each tile and just call the draw() method on each tile (still making sure to keep textureswaps to a minimum or gone completely).

To reposition an object on screen, should I glTranslate (I understand this will put pressure on the GPU) or would it be better to update update the FloatBuffer that holds the coordinates of the QUAD?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you're using OpenGL ES 2.0, then glTranslate() isn't available; it's only supported in OpenGL ES 1.X.

The best performing solution will depend on the platform you're using.  In particular, the underlying graphics architecture of the GPU (whether it's an immediate- or tiled-rendering system) will determine how many draw calls you can get away with in scene.  Because OpenGL ES doesn't have a quadrilateral primitive (e.g., GL_QUADS, as you can use in desktop OpenGL's compatibility profile), you'll either need to draw a sequence of pairs of triangles (each a triangle strip, each requiring its own draw call), or as a collection of independent triangles with each pair of triangles composing a single quad (this mode transforms more positions, but reduces the number of draw calls), or if you can do in your 1. suggestion, and keep track of all the quads that will use the same texture, you can draw one long triangle strip with degenerate triangles (ones with zero area, which won't be rasterized to the screen).  That'll take more geometry work, but can reduce the amount of texture swapping you need to do.

Finally, to the question of updating the buffer of vertex positions, that's also a going to be a platform-dependent solution, regardless, however, make a point of using *vertex buffer objects* (VBOs).  Almost all mobile GPUs will benefit from having your vertex data stored in that manner.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I believe VBOs are the way to go, so I'll take your advice.